# Transact-SQL Forcing a JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a report with a static number of rows.

Table #1 Field #1 is a list of all Items we currently sell. 
Table #2 Field #1 we have a list of all Locations that we sell from. 
Table #3 contains all sales date including Item Numbers and Location Codes

I currently have a select to give me a list of all Distinct Item Numbers (Lets say 1000 of them)

Before I left Join the sales data from Table #3 I want to find a way to increase my number of rows and make a distinct row for each location for every item.

I.e. if I have a 1000  items and 10 locations I want to have 10,000 rows so that I can left join sales date ON Item Number & Location Code. I want it this way so I will have a row even if there is no sales data.

Since we havent sold every item in every location a left join from the sales table will not accomplish this. **Also the Table with Locations has no common fields with Item table to join ON. Is there a different kind of JOIN or a different SQL function to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: yup, `CROSS JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `cross join` and `left join`.  For instance, to sum the sales:

```
select i.itemid, l.locationid, sum(t.sales)
from items i cross join
     locations l left join
     table3 t
     on i.itemid = t.itemid and l.locationid = t.locationid
group by i.itemid, l.locationid
order by i.itemid, l.locationid;
```

If you only have one row in `table3`, then the aggregation is not necessary.

Comment: Perfect! I knew there had to be a way. Thanks!!